# How can check email is exist or not, I mean email is real that is somebody have in firebase android app?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

You know some people are making up email to enter the app fastly. I want to check the user mail is real, not fake. I did some seacrhing , is there any other way without email verification? How can I control this situation?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some API options you can call to verify the existence of an email address. For example this [one](https://mailboxlayer.com/documentation) offers a Rest API for that.

If you meant inside firebase. Nope, there is no way. In my most recently app you can even create users with emails such as abc@mail.com and it accepts. It only validates for email format, not existence, so if you do something like abc@mail it will through an error.

Comment: Can I do without using API? Is there any alternative ways in firebase?

Comment: Same as my app :D Thank you so much for your answers @LeviAlbuquerque :)